# Issue with timestamp on model - expectations vary depending on the environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have a table:

```
  create_table "gocardless_runner_infos", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "runner_id", null: false
    t.string "redirect_flow_id"
    t.string "redirect_flow_url"
    t.string "mandate_id"
    t.string "customer_id"
    t.datetime "timestamp", precision: nil, null: false
  end
```

If I try to create an instance with `GocardlessRunnerInfo.create(runner_id: id, timestamp: DateTime.now)` I get an error `unknown attribute 'timestamp' for GocardlessRunnerInfo`

If I try to create it without setting a timestamp, so `GocardlessRunnerInfo.create(runner_id: id)`, then it will work in my dev and production environments, but my tests will error out with:

```
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "timestamp" of relation "gocardless_runner_infos" violates not-null constraint
      DETAIL:  Failing row contains (21, 1044890529, null, null, null, null, null).
       (ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation)
```

It's like my test schema is expecting the timestamp but dev and production isn't. Any ideas on what's going on?

Database is postgres

Comment: sounds like your production database needs to do a migration

Comment: but the behaviour is on both dev and production - I've run `rails db:migrate` on the dev environment

Comment: I suggest comparing their database schemas.

Comment: What database(s)? Postgres? MySQL? SQLite?

Comment: @Chiperific my bad it's postgres

Comment: In dev and prod, does the timestamp get generated or is it left nil?

Answer (score 0):

Your test database is the one performing as expected:

```bash
PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "timestamp" of relation "gocardless_runner_infos"
```

because you've set `null: false`:

```rb
    t.datetime "timestamp", precision: nil, null: false
```

There are a few potential causes:

1. Your `development` and `production` databases don't have this `not null` constraint.
2. Your `development` and `production` databases aren't Postgres, so the constraint is not being applied the same way
3. Your `development` and `production` databases have a default value like `"timestamp" TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NOW() NOT NULL` that is setting the value on creation so the `not null` constraint is satisfied.